# Website panel upload error "HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found"

Tags: windows-server-2008, website

I am uploading a 400MB file to the Website-panel file manager and get "HTTP Error 404.13 - Not Found". The log mentions verifying the configuration/system/.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestslimits@maxAllowedContentLength setting in the applicationhost.config or webconfig file.

How do I make changes to this file on Windows 2008 r2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applicationHost.config is located by default in `%WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\config\`.

You can also use the Request Filtering feature from the IIS Manager. For more information on configuring Request Filtering see [this configuration reference](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits)